# How do I resolve an 'unknown repository format: requires features 'largefiles' (upgrade Mercurial)' error with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc

My server is running Mercurial 2.6 via the Python Module, exposed by HTTPS via IIS 6.1 (Server 2008 R2).

I've verified that the Mercurial version has the largefiles extension build in, and I've converted my repository using the "hg lfconvert" command as per [the documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension).

My TortoiseHg client (v2.8.1) also has the extension built in and it's enabled in my global settings (Mercurial.ini).

When I attempt to clone the converted repository, I get the following error message as an HTTP error:

> HTTP Error: 500 (unknown repository format: requires features 'largefiles' (upgrade Mercurial))

As far as I can tell, I've enabled everything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable the extension in the repository as well, after its been converted with hglfconvert. This can be done by editting the .hg/hgrc file (create it if it doesn't exist).

I had to do this on the Mercurial server in my environment. I'm not positive whether this is the appropriate location, I just know this is what I had to do to get it working in our setup. YMMV.

Add the following lines:

```
[extensions]
largefiles=
```

Note again that this is applicable to repositories that have already been converted. Simply adding it to an existing repository likely won't do the trick.